# Can a char vector go out of bounds?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, segmentation-fault

I'm simply reading a string of number char by char until the '\n' is entered.

```
vector <char> pay;
vector <char> :: iterator p;
char x;
char maxdigit;
if(flag==1)
{
    cin.ignore();       // to ignore the first enter key press, after the test case         
    flag=0;
}

for(long long int i=0; ; i++)
{
    cin.get(x);     // The >> operator doesn't detect the ENTER key, so the loop won't end
    if(x=='\n') 
        break;
    pay.push_back(x);
}
```

Finding the max digit or the best digit to remove so as to minimize the entered number.

```
if(pay[1]=='0')
{
    pay.erase(pay.begin());
    while(pay[0]=='0')
        pay.erase(pay.begin());
}
else
{
    maxdigit=*max_element(pay.begin(),pay.end());
    p = find(pay.begin(),pay.end(),maxdigit);
    pay.erase(p);   
}
```

But I'm receiving a sigsegv error, Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: If the user presses enter right away without entering any number, the vector will be empty, and `if(pay[1]=='0')` will be out of bounds.

Comment: For testing you could replace all `[]` with `at()`, this will perform bounds checking and help you narrow down the location of the error.

Comment: The first part can be replaced by [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Have you used a debugger? That should point you to the error very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there ary many places in your code that can cause a seg fault (or other undefined behaviour):

```
if(pay[1]=='0') // UB if pay.size() < 2
{
    pay.erase(pay.begin());
    while(pay[0]=='0') // UB if pay.size() < 1, e.g. if pay is originally "00000" this loop has UB
        pay.erase(pay.begin()); // UB if pay.size() < 1
}
else
{
    maxdigit=*max_element(pay.begin(),pay.end()); // UB if pay is empty, max_element will return pay.end(), dereferencing this iterator is UB
    p = find(pay.begin(),pay.end(),maxdigit);
    pay.erase(p);   
}
```

Safer code would be:

```
if(!pay.empty() && pay.front()=='0') // I'm assuming pay[1]=='0' was meant to be pay[0]=='0'
{
    pay.erase(pay.begin());
    while(!pay.empty() && pay.front()=='0')
        pay.erase(pay.begin());
}
else
{
    p = max_element(pay.begin(),pay.end());
    if (p != pay.end())
    {
        maxdigit = *p;
        pay.erase(p);
    } 
}
```

Comment: The assumption pay[1]=='0' is not correct. Although I did forget to check if the vector was empty or not. Also I don't understand the  if (p != pay.end()) condition, I have to remove an element even if it's at the end of the vector.

Comment: `pay.end()` isn't the last element in the vector, it is the element after the last element in the vector, calling `*p` on `pay.end()` is undefined behaviour, `pay.erase(pay.end())` is also undefined. See the comments in the first block of code